# Facing the below exception System.ApplicationException:'Exception with an error code:0xa (SPXERR_INVALID_HEADER)' when detecting the language of audio

Tags: exception, speech-recognition

using speechrecognizer i was trying to fetch the language of the speech by following the code snippet

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

class Program
{
    async static Task FromFile(SpeechConfig speechConfig)
    {
        try
        {
            var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput("PathToFile.wav");
            var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

            var result = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={result.Text}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }
    }

    async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("3d29f22b12694e5cad8ab170639142a6", "northeurope");
        await FromFile(speechConfig);
    }
}
```

after executing above code i was facing the below exception
System.ApplicationException: 'Exception with an error code: 0x8 (SPXERR_FILE_OPEN_FAILED)'

Note: i was sending the proper .wav audio file

can anyone help on this issue?

expecting the language of the audio file